# Описание Delphi WebBrowser

Tags: delphi

Где можно получить справку по WebBrowser в Delphi. (Описание всех функций свойств и тд.)
На msdn есть описание только для C, C++ и др. Для Delphi не нашел...

Answer (score 1):

Свойства будут одинаковые что для Delphi что для C++ так что читайте MSDN

Answer (score 0):

- [FAQ по использованию компонента TWebBrowser](http://www.sources.ru/delphi/delphi_twebbrowser_faq.shtml)
- [Пример расширения возможностей TWebBrowser](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/Delphi/AdvancedTWebBrowser.xml)

Поскольку компонент TWebBrowser построен на основе элемента управления ActiveX WebBrowser, то интерфейс управления будет практически совпадать, поэтому вполне можно опираться на документацию MSDN.